# Android Java callback null inside broadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get notification when Android receives a text message, so I wrote a new class for that like this:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MyBroadcastCallback callback;

    public MyBroadcastReceiver() {}

    public MyBroadcastReceiver(MyBroadcastCallback callback) {
        this.callback=callback;
        Log.d("myTag", "MyBroadcastReceiver CONSTRUCTOR.... "+this.callback);
        this.callback.OnReceiveSMS("phone TEST","message TEST");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();

        if (intentExtras != null) {

            Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {

                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

                String phone = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                String message = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();

                this.callback.OnReceiveSMS(phone,message);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface MyBroadcastCallback {
        void OnReceiveSMS(String phone,String message);
    }
}
```

Then in my main activity I instantiate the class like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyBroadcastReceiver.MyBroadcastCallback {

    MyBroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        broadcastReceiver=new MyBroadcastReceiver(this);
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public void OnReceiveSMS(String phone, String message) {
        Log.d("myTag", "NEW SMS MESSAGE PHONE="+phone + " message="+message);
    }
}
```

The Android manifest looks like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When a text is received, `OnReceive` is called in the MyBroadCastReceiver class, that works great.

But when I try to call my own callback function inside `OnReceive()` to notify the main activity of the text message like this:

```
this.callback.OnReceiveSMS(phone, message);
```

It crashes with exception that `this.callback` is `null`.

I know it's not `null` in the beginning because in the constructor I pass in the main activity which implements that interface.

To debug I also printed out `this.callback` in the constructor and even called that function in there to make sure its not `null`, and all that works, but somehow it BECOMES `null` when a text comes in and Android OS calls `OnReceive`.

Does anybody knows why it's `null`? How to fix?

Comment: Problem is that if have created class object only. You also have to create broadcast intent filter for sms from activity and than you have to register broadcast from activity.
Also remove broadcast from manifest.xml.

Comment: The best option to pass value from receiver to activity is to use Local Broadcast Manager.

Comment: So I have to receive the big main SMS broadcast, then rebroadcast it to myself using local broadcast?

Comment: Thanks guys local broadcast worked!!!